Does Baldur's Gate 3's in-game mod manager disable achievements on Steam?
For Baldur's Gate 3 (and many other games), installing third-party mods disables the ability to earn achievements on Steam. It is possible, however, to install an additional mod specifically to turn achievements back on.
In Patch 7, Larian implemented an official, in-game mod manager.
When playing Baldur's Gate 3 via Steam, does installing a mod with the in-game mod manager disable Steam achievements?
If the answer is yes, is there a mod available from the in-game mod manager to re-enable achievements, or would one still have to rely on a third-party mod for this?

According to PCGamer, using mods from the official in-game mod manager will disable achievements. Additionally, the Achievement Enabler mod does not work with Patch 7.

[I] was still slightly frustrated to see that Steam achievements are disabled if you install anything from the official mod manager. The old cheater's refuge of the Achievement Enabler on the Nexus no longer seems to work, and also required all that faff and fiddling I want to avoid anyway.

